# pgAgent installation in PostgreSQL

Tags: 12.04, installation, postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.1 on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I try to run Aplication Stack Builder and install pgAgent.

At first I am asked for root password, which I provide, after I choose PostgreSQL 9.1 on port 5433 as the only option. On next screen I tick pgAgent and click Next a few times to get to the Setup screen with verification the postgradeSQL installation details. The Host is local, the User Name is postgres and I type my password for postgrade which I use when open pgAdmin III. When I click next I have a warning:

```
psql.bin: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) 
  and accepting TCP/IP connection on port 5432?
```

When I try pgAdmin it does work with password I provide but it looks for me like this password is not accepted by Stack Builder. I also provide my root password on the beginning so it should be able to do everything with sudo privilege. I don't know what to do now and what is the problem. Should I run something else before Stack Builder?

I know it seems like password problem but I tried all and it is not a simple password case. Did anyone have similar problem or know what to do?

Comment: Cross-post of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28498/pgagent-installation-with-stack-builder-in-postgresql . Please cross-link or don't cross-post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PgAgent-III and `psql` can use unix socket connections, while it looks like StackBuilder is using TCP/IP. Does:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 postgres
```

produce the same error? If so, check `postgresql.conf` and see what `listen_addresses` is set to; it might be set not to listen on TCP/IP. See the documentation for details and how to change it: [Runtime configuration parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html)

If the `port` directive in `postgresql.conf` is set to port other than the default port `5432` - say `5433` - you must specify that everywhere you connect. For example:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 postgres
```